# Select Each Host Name's utilization percentage based on highest timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by, rdbms

I have a table of cpu utilization data. Each row has a hostname, utilization percentage and timestamp. I want to select all host and cpu utilizationat highest time stamp for particular host.

Below is my table structure , inserts and selection

```
CREATE TABLE cpu_utilization
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  hostname character varying(255),
  "timestamp" bigint,
  cpuutilizationpercentage integer,
  CONSTRAINT cpu_utilization_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE cpu_utilization
  OWNER TO postgres;


INSERT INTO cpu_utilization
VALUES (1,'host1','111111',10);
INSERT INTO cpu_utilization
VALUES (2,'host1','111112',12);
INSERT INTO cpu_utilization
VALUES (3,'host1','111113',15);

INSERT INTO cpu_utilization
VALUES (4,'host2','111111',20);
INSERT INTO cpu_utilization
VALUES (5,'host2','111112',22);
INSERT INTO cpu_utilization
VALUES (6,'host2','111113',25);

INSERT INTO cpu_utilization
VALUES (7,'host3','111111',10);
```

And i am performing this select query

```
select * from cpu_utilization where timestamp in ( select max(timestamp) from cpu_utilization group by hostname );
```

The output what i am getting is -

```
id; hostname    timestamp   cpuutilizationpercentage
1;  "host1";    111111;     10
3;  "host1";    111113;     15
4;  "host2";    111111;     20
6;  "host2";    111113;     25
7;  "host3";    111111;     10
```

But i am expecting the output as -

```
id; hostname    timestamp   cpuutilizationpercentage
3;  "host1";    111113;     15
6;  "host2";    111113;     25
7;  "host3";    111111;     10
```

what's wrong with my select query, any idea?

Comment: Looks like today is the day for the similar questions. I have just answered a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430671/how-to-solve-this-using-a-subquery-in-a-from-clause/42430777#42430777

Comment: Just use a correlated subquery or an inner join

Comment: Your subquery returns two timestamps `111113` and `111111` which are max for different hostnames. Thus you get all rows with those timestamps. Use a correlated subquery as @cha suggested and `=` instead of `in`.

Comment: i didn't understand corelated subqueries much , but what i tried based on reference given me all rows of table as output. My query -             select * from report.cpu_utilization where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from report.cpu_utilization cpuutil where cpuutil.id=report.cpu_utilization.id group by hostname);

Answer (score 1):

thanks @cha, i was wrongly doing where clause on id, instead it should be on hostname.
I got the desired output with -

```
select * from cpu_utilization where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from cpu_utilization cpuutil where cpuutil.hostname=cpu_utilization.hostname);
```

Comment: good job. Also try with the inner join. The inner join version sometimes performs better comparing with the correlated subqueries